# Extract first 5 fields from semicolon-separated file

Tags: shell, csv

I have a semicolon-separated file with 10 fields on each line. I need to extract only the first 5 fields.

Input:

```
A.txt

1;abc  ;xyz  ;0.0000;3.0; ; ;0.00; ; xyz;
```

Output file:

```
B.txt
1;abc  ;xyz  ;0.0000;3.0;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can cut from field1-5:

```
cut -d';' -f1-5 file
```

If the ending `;` is needed, you can append it by other tool or using grep(assume your grep has `-P` option):

```
kent$  grep -oP '^(.*?;){5}' file
1;abc  ;xyz  ;0.0000;3.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

In `sed` you can match the pattern `string;` 5 times:

```
sed 's/\(\([^;]*;\)\{5\}\).*/\1/' A.txt
```

or, when your `sed`supports `-r`:

```
sed -r 's/(([^;]*;){5}).*/\1/' A.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cut -f-5 -d";" A.txt > B.txt
```

Where:
 - `-f` selects the fields (`-5` from start to 5)
 - `-d` provides a delimiter, (here the semicolon)

Comment: it misses the last ( 5th ) semicolon

Answer (score 0):

Given that the input is field-based, using `awk` is another option:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=";"; ORS=OFS"\n" } { NF=5; print }' A.txt > B.txt
```

<sup>If you're using BSD/macOS, insert `$1=$1;` after `NF=5;` to make this work.</sup>

- `FS=OFS=";"` sets both the input field separator, `FS`, and the output field separator, `OFS`, to a semicolon.

  - The input field separator is used to break each input record (line) into fields.
  - The output field separator is used to rebuild the record when individual fields are modified or the number of fields are modified.
- `ORS=OFS"\n"` sets the output *record* separator to a semicolon followed by a newline, given that a trailing `;` should be output.

  - Simply omit this statement if the trailing `;` is undesired.
- `{ NF=5; print }` truncates the input record to 5 fields, by setting `NF`, the number (count) of fields to 5 and then prints the modified record.

  - It is at this point that `OFS` comes into play: the first 5 fields are concatenated to form the output record, using `OFS` as the separator.
  - Note: BSD/macOS Awk doesn't modify the record *just* by setting `NF`; you must additionally *modify a field explicitly* for the changed field count to take effect: a dummy operation such as `$1=$1` (assigning field 1 to itself) is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3}' A.txt >B.txt

1;abc  ;xyz  ;0.0000;3.0;
```